# Как склеить массивы Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть исходное изображение 640х480. Извлекаю из него вектора R, G, B. Потом нужно обратно склеить, чтобы восстановилось изображение с формой (480,640,3). У меня получается форма (3,480,640):

```
# Исходные вектора
r = np.arange(480*640)
g = np.arange(480*640)
b = np.arange(480*640)

    # Попытка 1
r_2 = r.reshape(480, 640)
g_2 = g.reshape(480, 640)
b_2 = b.reshape(480, 640)
img = np.hstack([r_2, g_2, b_2])
img = np.array(np.hsplit(img, 3))

    # Попытка 2
img = np.column_stack((r, g, b))
img = frame.reshape(480*640, 3)
img = np.array(np.vsplit(img, 480))     
img = np.uint8(img)
cv2.imshow("img" , img) # Наблюдаю три изображения в окне
```

Comment: вам точно вторая размерность нужна 5?

Comment: ошибся. У меня есть вектора R, G, B. Нужно склеить R,G,B, чтобы изображение собралось обратно

Comment: Если используете cv2, то там есть cv2.split и cv2.merge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам, вероятно. нужен метод dstack:

```
res = np.dstack((r,g,b))
print(res.shape)
```

> (480, 640, 3)